# How to 'flip' dichotomous effector variable in a bivariate logistic regression in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to conduct a bivariate logistic regression in R, however, I have the effector variable flipped. Essentially, what I'm trying to see is how a 'checked'

EDIT: I figured out an easy fix so thanks everyone for the help. I just created a new dichotomous variable and set 'Unchecked' = 0 and 'Checked' = 1 as follows-

```
d2$pmh = 0
d2$pmh[d2$Past.Medical.History..choice.Overweight.Obese.. == "Unchecked"] = 0
d2$pmh[d2$Past.Medical.History..choice.Overweight.Obese.. == "Checked"] = 1
```

Then I just use the new variable for the regression and it resolves my issue.

Console Output following entry:

[image]

Comment: You question is incomplete, but you don't need to flip your response variable. If you flipped it, your intercept would be ( -0.4700) + (-0.5876) = -1.0576 and the coefficient for checked would be the negative of its current value (i.e. 0.5876)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a picture, not copy/pasteable and I don't want to type out that terrible variable name, so I'm going to call it `Type2Diabetes`.

```
d2$Type2Diabetes = factor(d2$Type2Diabetes, levels = c("Unchecked", "Checked"))
```

This will modify the variable so that it is a factor (categorical) variable (if it wasn't already) and set the order of the categories to have "Unchecked" first. The first level is used as the default/intercept in the regression.